# IBMXMSDotnetClient 9.1.4 and Up Will Only Pick Up Messages On Queue Once Then Stalls

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

We have an existing C# XMS client that works pretty well and we are using amqmxmsstd.dll 9.1.3.  Now that we decided to upgrade and use the Nuget Package to manage our dependency instead (https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMXMSDotnetClient) we have tried with versions 9.1.4 through the latest 9.2.2 and for each test, we drop a message or a few on the queue, it picks them up, then we drop another after those are done being picked up and nothing.  The messages just sit there.  We have a connection exception listener and no problems there.  Drop back to the 9.1.3 client and it works fine.  Can't seem to find any documentation as to any changes from 9.1.3 as to why this would happen.

We develop locally using the IBM MQ Container which is at MQ version 9.2.0.0.  The 9.1.3 client works fine against it.  Our production servers are at 9.1.3, so I suppose we can just keep the client at 9.1.3, but thought there may be some improvements, but fixes, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think there is an APAR that has gone in for this issue. See post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571907/ibm-mq-xms-message-listener-fetching-only-the-messages-which-is-already-availabl

Comment: Note this is fixed on 9.2.0.2.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought we were experiencing the same behavior in 9.2.2.0 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMMQDotnetClient).  I'll run some more tests...

Comment: I meant https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMXMSDotnetClient (XMS).

Comment: 9.2.0.2 has the same problem...

Comment: Looks like it must have slipped,  the other question liked above stated IBM expected it to be fixed in 9.2.0.2, but I confirmed it is not listed on the 9.2.0.2 fix list.

Comment: 9.2.3 is now out (https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMXMSDotnetClient).  Checking to see if this was fixed. @JoshMc, where is this fix list?  I don't see one in the release notes...

Comment: Just search for "IBM MQ 9.1 LTS fixlist" or "IBM MQ 9.1 CD fixlist" to see the list of fixes for each level.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't see the fix listed in the list unfortunately (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/fix-list-ibm-mq-version-92x-continuous-delivery).  I'll still try out the new client when I get a chance...

Comment: IT34722 will be released with fixpack  | v9.2 LTS   9.2.0.4  | v9.x CD    9.2.5 |
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT34722

Comment: Does it work for someone on XMS version 9.2.0.4 from nuget? I downgraded from 9.2.4 (9.2.5 is scheduled for Q1 2022) and it still doesn't work for me. That's why I am curious if there is a problem with my code or if this version still doesn't fix it.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest Nuget 9.2.4 and problem still persists.  IBM fix list can be difficult to understand but it does not look like the fix has made it into the Nuget yet.  Waiting for 9.2.5.

Comment: The fix is not available in 9.2.4 and 9.2.5 has not been released yet. But according to the ticket linked below, it should be fixed in LTS version 9.2.0.4 which is released on nuget. The issue is that it still doesn't work for me, and I'm not sure if it's because of my code or because of the library.

Comment: I don't see 9.2.0.4 on nuget.  Just 9.2.4.  The release documentation does not appear to me to say you can get 9.2.0.4 on nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMXMSDotnetClient ).  Rather you have to download it from Fix Central (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/downloading-ibm-mq-9204).

Comment: @sac80644 It is available on nuget. It came out three months ago. It's under the versions tab on the site you linked to (https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMXMSDotnetClient/9.2.0.4).

Comment: @grzegorzorwat I don't know why I did not see it on the versions tab.  thanks!  so I just tested it out and it works.  I started my client, dropped some messages, it picked them up.  in the past I would drop some more after it was done processing those messages and it would not pick any more up.  but now it does successfully pick up subsequent messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an APAR IT34722 that has gone in for this issue.See post [IBM MQ XMS Message Listener fetching only the Messages which is already available in Queue and not a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571907/ibm-mq-xms-message-listener-fetching-only-the-messages-which-is-already-availabl)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I'm experiencing.  I'll keep an eye on it.  Surprised this has not been resolved since 9.1.4...